# How to execute a command from a certain directory in Inno Setup script

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have multiple `cmd` commands which is about installing `npm` components. I don't want to use batch file for this purpose. How can I execute these commands through `Exec` function in an Inno Sectum script and I want the installer to wait until these commands get executed?

Here are some example commands I wish to execute also they need to be executed on specified directory:

```
npm install forever-monitor
npm install ip
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inno Setup [`Exec` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_exec) takes `WorkingDir` as the third parameter.

So you can do

```pascal
Exec('npm', 'install forever-monitor', ExpandConstant('{pf}\nodejs'),
     SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

---

Though in this case, I would question, whether `npm` really needs to be executed from its directory. It is likely, that all you actually need is to execute `npm` with a full path:

```pascal
Exec(ExpandConstant('{pf}\nodejs\npm'), 'install forever-monitor', '',
     SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```